# How to calculate total working hour in 00:00 format?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview which have a column named as hour in format 00:00 i want to calculate total hours and display in a text box.

UPDATE:Example 2:10+3:50=6:00

My coed so far:

```
Protected Sub grdWork_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim txtHours As TextBox
        txtHours = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("txtHours"), TextBox)
        Dim Hours1 As String = txtHours.Text

        Dim Hours2 As String = "2:50"

        Dim TS1 As New TimeSpan(Integer.Parse(Hours1.Split(":"c)(0)), Integer.Parse(Hours1.Split(":"c)(1)), 0)

        If txtHours.Text <> "" Then
            'TotalChargeableValue = TotalChargeableValue + Convert.ToDouble(txtHours.Text)
            'Dim ts2 As TimeSpan



            'Dim TS2 As New TimeSpan(Integer.Parse(Hours2.Split(":"c)(0)), Integer.Parse(Hours2.Split(":"c)(1)), 0)


            ts2 = ts2.Add(TS1)
            'ts2 = TS1

            Session("timespan") = ts2

            'ts2 = ts2.Add(TS1)
            txtSum.Text = ts2.ToString()
            'MsgBox(TS3.ToString())

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: are you getting any errors? what is the problem?

Comment: It is not calculating exact time.@Jonny

Comment: Can you give an example of your values and what your code is calculating as the total.

Comment: Your question and sample code do not match. You say you want to calculate `2:10+3:50` but you are casting the value to a double which cannot be in the format of `2:10` or `3:50`. I suspect your format is wrong. can you give an example of what you would expect to find in txtHours, and what the datatype is of TotalChargeableHours please?

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan t1 = TimeSpan.Parse("23:30");
TimeSpan t2 = TimeSpan.Parse("00:40:00");
TimeSpan t3 = t1.Add(t2);
Console.WriteLine(t3); // 1.00:10:00
```

With DateTime:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse("23:30");
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse("00:40:00");
DateTime d3 = d1.Add(d2.TimeOfDay); 
Console.WriteLine(d3.TimeOfDay); // 00:10:00
```

Comment: Please use VB as the person asking this question may not know c# and find this answer to be useless.

Comment: @Jonny then they will use a converter like http://converter.telerik.com/ We're trying to help, let's not make us code in the language they want... we're here mostly to point them in the right direction, not actually do their "homework".